# Keychron K2 Fn lock solve in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, function-keys

On Linux, the Keychron K2 doesn't register any of the F1-F12 function keys as actual F keys, instead, treating them as multimedia keys by default. How to fix it?

They keyboard has 2 modes: Windows/Android and MacOS, but neither mode worked properly out of the box.

Comment: Here's my script for the fix https://github.com/timabell/dotmatrix/blob/c557c6e5f32d613c2183d99426ab56bccfc4debb/hardware/keychron-k2.sh - has some links in it. Info came from here: https://gist.github.com/andrebrait/961cefe730f4a2c41f57911e6195e444

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this:

1. Set the keyboard to Windows mode via the side switch
2. Use <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (hold for 4 seconds) to set the function key row to "Function" mode. (usually that's all that's necessary on Windows)
3. Run: `echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode`

Once complete the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys will work properly, and holding <kbd>Fn</kbd> turns them into multimedia keys. You can use the evtest utility to check how keyboard keys are registering until you get the above combination of settings configured properly.

To make this change persistent add a module option for hid_apple:

```
echo "options hid_apple fnmode=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf
```

You may need to rebuild your initramfs if hid_apple is included. - Ubuntu: `sudo update-initramfs -u - arch: mkinitcpio -P`

See also:

- /u/fratdaddyZC's comment on Reddit for the [fnmode tip](https://www.reddit.com/r/MechanicalKeyboards/comments/d5io49/comment/f0m2u14/)
- Kurgol's keychron repo of tips - [K2 manual](https://github.com/IulianDita/keychron/blob/master/k2.md)