# F1-F12 keys behaves as function keys after upgrade to 22

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have keychron k5 b1 keyboard. On ubuntu 18 everything was working fine but after upgrade all f keys have function behaviour by default. F12 does not open a guake terminal asit should - instead it increaces the volume....

Did anyone occured the same issue? How can I fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: Might want to see https://askubuntu.com/questions/818413/how-can-i-toggle-the-fn-function-key but it sounds like you need to either Enable or Disable Fn-Lock.

Comment: everything works fine on laptop's keyboard - its the issue with external keyboard. fn + esc does not work

Comment: Function lock is at the keyboard level.  The Fn key is not seen by the OS, so there is nothing that the OS can do to enable those keys to the way that you want them to be.  Your Keychron might be using the same key functions as the K2.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1484286/keychron-k2-fn-lock-solve-in-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: i checked the bios and action keys mode is disabled.... so it should only work that way with fn key but it doesn't :(

Comment: ok.. it works but on Mac mode. Interesting. On Win mode doesnt work ;D All good for now. Thanks for help.

Comment: You are more than welcome to write up your findings as an answer below to help others with the same type of keyboard experiencing the same issue as yours.

Comment: I did everything what was described in the link you provided. It says we should do that on Win mode but it didnt work..  worked on mac mode though.